# Modify the CSS (width) of a dialog

Tags: jquery, css, dialog

I use a dialog that contains div etc.
It is defined by :

```
$dialogContent2.dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: "S\351lectionner une activit\351",
    close: function () {
        $dialogContent2.dialog("destroy");
        $dialogContent2.hide();
    },
    buttons: [{
        ...
    }]
});
```

Is it possible to define the width of the dialog ?

I've tried to modify it directy in my css file, and to modify the width of each contained element, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Are you trying to set the width dynamically, or do you just want to use `width : "500px"`?

Comment: Just something like width : 500px would be fine

Comment: I'm going to be mean for a second and if you go to http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ and click options. You'll see width at the bottom. You should try documentation before just posting a question :)

Comment: There is a width constructor argument / getter setter, lookup width under options @ http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: @Steven [please see the Community Bulletin on the right.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/?cb=1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

You can specify the Width, it is an option:

**Code examples**

Initialize a dialog with the width option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ width: 460 });
```

Get or set the width option, after init.

//getter

```
var width = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "width" );
```

//setter

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "width", 460 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dialogContent2.dialog({
    width:480,
    modal: true,
    title: "S\351lectionner une activit\351",
    close: function () {
        $dialogContent2.dialog("destroy");
        $dialogContent2.hide();
    },
    buttons: [{
        ...
    }]
});
```

Comment: I hadn't seen the width option, I'm very sorry. Thank you for your help !

Comment: No problem. This method is much easier than trying to control it in a style sheet.